# Removing default values from result of jQuery serialize with regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am building a hash based on radio button groups a user has manipulated on a page. To ensure only relevant information is included in the URL, I would like to exclude fields that are still set to their default values. Rather than loop through the fields myself, I think jQuery serialize and a little regular expression would be more efficient.
However, this regular expression leaves the last default value in the resulting hash. Other variations I've tried removed too many or too few ampersands. Can anyone suggest a pattern for removing fields set to default regardless of their position in the hash?

Here is a sample of the HTML and the JavaScript (with the regex). There are about a dozen toggle groups in the full page and they would have labels, etc.

```js
function action() {
    console.log($('#formId').serialize().replace(/toggle(\d*)=default(&:?)/g, ''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formId">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4on" name="toggle4" value="on">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4off" name="toggle4" value="off">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4default" name="toggle4" value="default">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5on" name="toggle5" value="on">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5off" name="toggle5" value="off">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5default" name="toggle5" value="default">
</form>

<button onclick="action()">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that would help in my opinion.  Don't use `onclick=""`, use jQuery.  Secondly, you don't have to serialize the form, you can serialize a list of *input* elements so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.js-submit').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.closest("form").find("input:not(.js-default-value)").serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formId">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4on" name="toggle4" value="on">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4off" name="toggle4" value="off">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4default" name="toggle4" class="js-default-value" value="default">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5on" name="toggle5" value="on">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5off" name="toggle5" value="off">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5default" name="toggle5" class="js-default-value" value="default">
   <button class="js-submit" type="button">Show</button>
</form>
```

You'll have to modify the `find()` if you plan on using other types of inputs (buttons, textarea etc), but the code can exclude those as well by applying the default class.

Comment: Yeah, someone else wrote the onclick. :)

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton @ Google](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: Someone else edited my code on here. I wouldn't do it the way that it is written.

Comment: @LeeFloyd you can always roll back changes, I don't think the edits are appropriate for sure.

Answer (score 2):

> Rather than loop through the fields myself, I think jQuery serialize and a little regular expression would be more efficient.

That won't be more efficient. Regexes are expensive and error-phrone. I Would recommend to loop over the fields with jQuery and remove the unneeded values.

Example:

```js
function isDefaultValue(elem)
{
   return $(elem).val() == "default"; //skip if default value
}


function action() {
    var value = $('#formId input').filter(function(index, el){ 
         return !isDefaultValue(el)
    }).serialize();
    
    console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formId">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4on" name="toggle4" value="on">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4off" name="toggle4" value="off">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle4default" name="toggle4" value="default">
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5on" name="toggle5" value="on">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5off" name="toggle5" value="off">
    <input type="radio" id="toggle5default" name="toggle5" value="default">
</form>

<button onclick="action()">Show</button>
```